# iOS Simulator Mobile Safari

Tags: safari, games, web-browser, xcode-simulator

I might possibly have a html5 game project coming up, that would need to run on iOS devices. However i dont own many of them, nor do i have the money to buy them. My friend did remind me i might be able to simulate on the iOS simulator, but im not so sure. My mac is currently experiencing some problems so i cannot check it for myself. But it would help if someone could answer:

- Does the iOS simulator have safari browser on it? If so, how accurate
- would you say it is at displaying html5 games?

Answer (score 3):

The iOS simulator does have a Safari browser. Though the Safari browser found on the iOS and OS X are both based on WebKit, they are not exactly identical. So the Safari browser on the iOS is an approximation, not an accurate.

In addition, the WebKit on OS X is optimized to take advantage of the hardware in current Mac which at present performs faster than the slower hardware in current iOS devices.

I'd suggest that while it's possible to develop using the iOS simulator, it's best to test (for performance and reliability/crash) on the actual iOS device.